# Publishing Project vb.net Including Resources in Application Files

Tags: vb.net, flash

Im making a Project with swf file resources using VB.net. i try to publish my project and found out that all my resources(swf file) were not included in the application file after i publish it.

I just wanna ask if it is possible to include the all my resources files in the publish project?

i want to post image but i dont have yet reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to change the Build Action value to "Content" and Copy To Output Directory to either "Always Copy" or "Copy if Newer" in the properties pane.
[image]

Comment: Iv try what u said to change the properties of my resources file in to "copy always" or "copy if newer" but my resources file still not included in my application file when i publish it.